# Heat.exe why does it create different Registry keys to Regasm?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, heat

I am trying to use heat to create the necessary registry keys.  The assembly is a simple dummy **Shell Context handler** it adds a context menu to a .txt ending.

If I use **Regasm** to register it then a registry key (not the only one but the one that is different) is added at this.  Note that it is at txtfile.

`[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shellex]
  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers]
  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{1e25bcd5-f299-496a-911d-51fb901f7f40}]
    @="VBShellExtContextMenuHandler.FileContextMenuExt Class"`

If I use heat then this **txtfile** is not used.  It uses .txt

`[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\shellex]
  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers]
  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{1e25bcd5-f299-496a-911d-51fb901f7f40}]
    @="VBShellExtContextMenuHandler.FileContextMenuExt Class"`

The other keys that regasm makes seem to be the same as Heat but this one is not and it means that the menu fails with the Heat keys.

Is this a known problem with heat?

I know I could simply change it but this is a test and I need to add about 15 extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at a gotcha in the help topic [Regasm.exe (Assembly Registration Tool)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Note that the .reg file does not contain any registry updates that can
>   be made by user-defined register functions. Note that the /regfile
>   option only emits registry entries for managed classes. This option
>   does not emit entries for TypeLibIDs or InterfaceIDs.

I'm not 100% certain on Heat's interaction with Regasm but I know InstallShield's .NET Com Interop calls Regasm /regfile so this gotcha would apply.

Personally I only use these tools as one of many tools at my disposal to gather the requirements, sort it all out and then author it by hand.